# PayPal ExpressCheckout ignores discount

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I disovered a wired issue using Paypal **ExpressCheckout** with discounts:

I pass 2 Items like:

```
L_NAME0 : "test2",
L_AMT0: 2, // 2 EUR
L_QTY0: 1
```

and

```
L_NAME1 : "Discount",
L_AMT1: -0.60, // 60 cent
L_QTY1: 1
```

After redirect to Paypal everything seems fine:

[image: paypal_bug_lol]

But after closing this transaction, paypal charges the full amount (2 EUR) from my paypal-account:

[image: paypal order confirmation]

What is wrong with this paypal discount? It seems to be cheating on the customer and he must feel betrayed. 
I dont believe its paypals fault, so any ideas on what i did wrong are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you applied the discount line item to your SetExpressCheckout call, but the DoExpressCheckoutPayment call must not have had the same thing..??

You need to make sure DECP has all of the same line item details in it.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the point. You saved my day!